# Python Raw Socket to Ethernet Interface (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, sockets, dhcp

I'm trying to create a DHCP Server and the first step is for me to send packets through my ethernet port. I'm trying to send packets to my Ethernet interface and having an error popping up.

The code is below.

```
import socket

def sendeth(src, dst, eth_type, payload, interface = "eth0"):
  """Send raw Ethernet packet on interface."""

  assert(len(src) == len(dst) == 6) # 48-bit ethernet addresses
  assert(len(eth_type) == 2) # 16-bit ethernet type

  #s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)

  # From the docs: "For raw packet
  # sockets the address is a tuple (ifname, proto [,pkttype [,hatype]])"
  s.bind((interface, 0))
  return s.send(src + dst + eth_type + payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Sent %d-byte Ethernet packet on eth0" %
    sendeth("\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\x7A\x05",
            "hello"))
```

I was having issues with the way the socket was being created. AF_PACKET is not recognized so I'm assuming that only works for Linux. I commented it out and added a new line below it. I ran it again and I started getting an error shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eth.py", line 27, in <module>
    "hello"))
  File "eth.py", line 19, in sendeth
    s.bind((interface, 0))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: what are you passing in for interface? "eth0" won't work on Windows.

Comment: Indeed, in my modest experience with windows sockets, interface names are usually incomprehensible. There were even a third-party module to handle them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DHCP is a UDP protocol. You shouldn't need a raw socket to implement a DHCP server.

Use an AF_INET/SOCK_DGRAM socket, and bind to address 255.255.255.255 in order to implement your server.

Comment: Thank you. This makes my life a lot easier. After receiving the message on the socket binded to 255.255.255.255 I have to handle the message and send back the information for the client to set it's IP. Slightly out of the scope of this thread, do you know a place that describes this interaction? Or do i have to dive into the RFC2131 documentation?

Answer (score 5):

As said multiple times already, `ETH_P_ALL` is **not implemented on Windows**, due to Win32 limitations.
The alternative is called **Winpcap** (more recently **Npcap**), which sets up Windows to access such low-level things (it adds an extra driver)

What you can do then is to use a **Winpcap/Npcap based** library such as [Scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), to access Raw low-level sockets. This requires to install Npcap (or Winpcap) on the computer.

Then you can either use the library as-is (it has lots of capabilities of handling packets), or if you want to have access to the raw data

```
from scapy.all import *
IFACES.show() # let’s see what interfaces are available. Windows only
iface = <<"full iface name">> or <<IFACES.dev_from_index(12)>> or <<IFACES.dev_from_pcapname(r"\\Device_stuff")>>
socket = conf.L2socket(iface=iface)
# socket is now an Ethernet socket
### RECV
packet_raw = socket.recv_raw()[0]  # Raw data
packet_decoded = socket.recv() # Using the library (also contains things like sent time...)
### SEND
socket.send(b"\x00......"). # send raw data
socket.send(Ether()/IP(dst="www.google.com")/TCP()/Raw(load=b"data")) # use library
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - I just need to replace `recv_raw()[0]` with `recv_raw()[1]` to get raw data.
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.supersocket.html#scapy.supersocket.SuperSocket.recv_raw

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't get access to ethernet with this socket:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
```

`socket.IPPROTO_RAW` gives you access to Level 3 protocol (IP), whereas ethernet is on Level 1 and 2. At level 3 an ethernet frame is already analyzed and its headers discarded. You need to get to Level 2 and `ETH_P_ALL` protocol seems to be a nice place to start. I don't believe python `socket` module implements it on that low level, but you can interact with WinAPI via `ctypes` module.

Comment: When I try to use ETH_P_ALL I get an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ETH_P_ALL'

Comment: @Sam Yes, ETH_P_ALL isn't implemented in `socket`. You have to work directly with WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

This example from the docs seems instructive.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

# receive a package
print s.recvfrom(65565)

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

I think the key is socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()). "eth0" as used in your example won't be supported on Windows.

Comment: What would happen if I have multiple interfaces?

Comment: hmmm... gethostbyname returns an IP address.  Maybe try bind with the IP address assigned to the physical interface you want?

Answer (score 0):

Approaching your question from another direction: why do you need to work with ethernet at all? DHCP is usually implemented via UDP.

1. DHCP server always has some IP address (and a pool of addresses it can lease).
2. If a client wants and IP (DHCP actually can do much more than just assign IPs but let's stop on this use case for now), it sends a broadcast DHCPREQUEST with source IP 0.0.0.0 and destination IP 255.255.255.255. The servers answer him via UDP broadcast as well, but with his own source IP.

If you want to create an implementation of DHCP, starting with OSI Level 2 (ethernet) will just give you headache of maintaining Level 3 (IP) and 4 (UDP). I don't see any benefit in this.

If you'd like to create a DHCP-like protocol based on ethernet be ready to work on the following issue: routers don't forward broadcast packets unless asked to do so. For instance, for Cisco routers it looks like this:

```
router(config)# interface ethernet 0/0
router(config-if)# ip helper-address 10.1.23.5
router(config-if)# end
router#
```

Thus we configure router so it knows there's something helpful connected to ethernet 0/0 port with IP 10.1.23.5 that needs broadcasts ([source](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/13916/router-not-forwarding-dhcp-requests-hosts-are-unable-obtain-ip-address-dhcp-server)).